# How to detect remote desktop connection on windows?

Tags: java, windows

I'd like to write `java` tool to run in the background of my PC. It should detect remote desktop connections.

My goal is to trigger a certain task whenever I log into my workpc from home. And also run another task when I close the remote desktop session.

Is that possible at all?

One alternative might be the windows `task scheduler` and fire a task on remote session logon and logout. Eg I could launch a tool that fires an event to my target java application. But maybe these events can directly be caught inside java?

The windows `Security Log Events` are as follows:

```
528 Login
538 Logoff
```

But how could I get them?

Comment: A logon/logoff script (gpo) that runs your app which checks to see if SM_REMOTESESSION is set to determine if its running under terminal services?